# Rails server not working properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails 4.1.4 application starting in development on `http://0.0.0.0:3000`

```
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/home/techbirds/aniket/config/initializers/address_states.rb:1:in  <top (required)>': uninitialized constant Country (NameError)
```

Comment: paste your `config/initializers/address_states.rb` file

Answer (score 0):

Look at the error carefully:

```
home/techbirds/aniket/config/initializers/address_states.rb:1:in ': uninitialized constant Country (NameError)
```

In your `config/initializers/address_states.rb` file's line number 1, you have used `Country` class or module which is not loaded properly, that is why your `rails server` is not working. Make sure you have a `Country` class or module defined in your project and if it is, then make sure it is loaded properly (e.g require the file that has the `Country` class or module).

Also, take a look at the [Autoloading and Reloading Constants Documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html) which will give you some more information.